# Emacs GTK keybindings theme in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, gtk, emacs, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to enable Emacs GTK keybindings in a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04, but it doesn't seem to take effect.
What I have already tried:

- enabling it in `gnome-tweak-tool`
- executing `gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme Emacs --type string`
- executing `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme "Emacs"`
- adding `gtk-key-theme-name = "Emacs"` to my `~/.gtkrc-2.0`

None of those seemed to work. What am I missing?

**EDIT**
I just realized it's working for GTK2 apps. So it's not applying only for GTK3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like it's a bug of GNOME 3.6
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1131919

I upgraded to GNOME 3.8 and it seems to work properly now.